# Docker Containers in swarm can not see eachother

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, redis, docker-swarm

I’m just beginning to learn docker. I have a swarm running, and I’m trying to get my asp.net core app to communicate with a redis server. I didn’t think I would have this many issues with it :(

My docker-compose:

```
version: ‘3.3’

services:
   webfarm_api:
     image: dispersia/webfarm.api
     ports:
       - 8080:80
     environment:
       - SERVICE_PORTS=8080
     depends_on:
       - webfarm_redis

  webfarm_redis:
    image: dispersia/redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ‘redis:/data’

volumes:
  redis:
```

I have set my redis.conf to bind to 0.0.0.0, and in my app I have

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = “0.0.0.0”;
    options.InstanceName = “redisInstance”;
});
```

If I manually run a redis-server and my asp.net core app outside of docker, they see eachother and everything works, but I can’t for the life of me get it to work inside of docker.

If I run docker inspect network prod_default I get that both containers are running, and they do have different IP’s (10.0.0.6/24) and (10.0.0.4/24) However I thought that 0.0.0.0 would allow any container to see it within the same network. If I’m wrong in my assumption of that, please let me know.

Is this the correct way of making these containers communicate?

Thanks

Comment: Also please note, your containers are **NOT** in the same network. You have no "networks" section in your docker-compose. See [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks)

Comment: @Tseng when I initialize my compose file through a swarm, it creates a default network based on the name, such as: `docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml prod` will create a `prod_bridge` and will automatically connect any container opened through it under that network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Description of 127.0.0.1 vs 0.0.0.0 taken from https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0

**What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?**

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address (also known as localhost).

`0.0.0.0` is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target (a no particular address placeholder).

In the context of a route entry, it usually means the default route.

> In the context of servers, `0.0.0.0` means "all IPv4 addresses on the
>   local machine". If a host has two IP addresses, `192.168.1.1` and
>   `10.1.2.1`, and a server running on the host listens on `0.0.0.0`, it will be reachable at both of those IPs.

So what does this mean? It means that in your isolated application container you are telling the application to look at the localhost for a `Redis` instance at this port, which isn't true as `Redis` is running in a separate isolated `Redis` container.

What you are wanting to do is use your `webfarm_redis` name in your app which is going to ask the Docker DNS service where is `webfarm_redis` and it will give you the docker's `Redis` IP.

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = “webfarm_redis”;
    options.InstanceName = “redisInstance”;
});
```

I would pass the `webfarm_redis` as an environmental variable so that it can be changed without a re-build.

Comment: So I did try this route before, and thanks for the information, how would you pass webfarm_redis as an environment variable though? When I tried to put the string directly in it, it didn't work, and when I tried to put an actual environment variable like: `REDIS_SERVER=webfarm_redis` and then use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('REDIS_SERVER') it just returned webfarm_redis as a string again instead of the address to that container

Comment: It wouldn't pass the IP. The case being, what you start 5 Redis containers in a swarm. Which one would you use or should docker give you? So if you use the name then docker can give you the best redis container at that second. If the next second the container dies, it would give you the next best container.

Comment: Finally got to try it, and it works. Thank you so much. I must have had some other configuration off before.